# Как поставить offline , ceph - deploy

Tags: ubuntu

Имеется сервер без интернета, убунту 18.04 , необходимо на нее поставить ceph, , через ceph-deploy.
Как выкачать зависимости ceph, для установки оффлайн ?

Comment: `aptitude show ceph-deploy`, `Зависимости: python-pkg-resources, python:any (< 2.8), python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)`Скоре всего тебе надо просто через `aptitude download <пакет>` выкачать руками всё нужное.

Comment: ок спасибо, буду выкачивать руками !